# Boolean value doesnt change

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS code:

```
var name_valid = false;
$("#InputName").blur( function(){
  if ($(this).val() != ""){
    name_valid = true;
  } else {
    name_valid = false;
  }
});
if (name_valid === true){
  alert('ok');
}
console.log(name_valid);
```

I don't actually understand why my code is not working.
If my `<input>` is not empty I have to get alert ('ok'), but I don't get anything.
Why my `boolean` value is still `false` at the end?

Comment: You made a little mistake. see my answer.

Comment: Hi @MiCol. If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting and upvoting it. This indicates to the wider community that you have found a solution for your question and also earns both you and the answer some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a callback function, which executes only after the blur function is complete. This means that this line `if (name_valid === true)` is executing before this line `if ($(this).val() != "")`.

Try changing your code to this:

```
var name_valid = false;
$("#InputName").blur( function(){
  if ($(this).val() != ""){
    name_valid = true;
  } else {
    name_valid = false;
  }

  if (name_valid === true){
     alert('ok');
   }
  console.log(name_valid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a little mistake, you should put your last `if` statement inside callback function, like below:

```
var name_valid = false;
$("#InputName").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        name_valid = true;
    } else {
        name_valid = false;
    }
    if (name_valid === true) {
        alert('ok');
    }
    console.log(name_valid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional only runs on page load. You want it inside the event handler so it runs when the event actually gets triggered

```
var name_valid = false;
$("#InputName").blur(function() {

  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    name_valid = true;
  } else {
    name_valid = false;
  }

  if (name_valid === true) {
    alert('ok');
  }
  console.log(name_valid);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name_valid = false;
$("#InputName").blur( function(){
  if ($(this).val() !== ""){
    name_valid = true;
  }
  if (name_valid === true){
      alert('ok');
  }
  console.log(name_valid);
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name_valid;
    $("input").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            name_valid = true;
        } else {
            name_valid = false;
        }
        if (name_valid) {
            alert('ok');
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Might you add a bit of explanation as to what was wrong and how your code fixes it?